# A closed, bounded set not of the form $[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis

This is for **real** analysis. Could someone provide an example?

Comment: You can take $\{a,b\}$.

Comment: With $a\neq b$.

Comment: If you want the set to be infinite, you can take a convergent sequence together with its limit point, e.g., $$\{0\}\cup\left\{\frac1n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\}\;.$$

Comment: $[a,b]\cup[c,d]$, with $a<b<c<d$

Comment: @BaronVT: Incorrect. What if $a<c<d<b$? You probably just mean (in words) "the union of two disjoint closed intervals".

Comment: Thanks, fixed now. Yeah, I never take enough care in writing "comment answers". What I usually mean is "the 'obvious' version of this kind of example, not the pathological one"

Comment: The Cantor set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you are thinking of closed sets $[a,b]$ where $a \neq b$. However, the set will still be closed if $a=b$ as $[a,a] = \{a \}$, so singletons are closed. Further, the union of finitely many closed sets is closed, so for any finite collection of points $\{x_i\}^n_{i=1}$ we know $$\bigcup_{i=1}^n \{x_i\} = \{x_i\}^n_{i=1}$$ is closed. More generally, given collections  $\{a_i\}^n_{i=1}, \space  \{b_i\}^n_{i=1}$ where $a_1 \leq b_1 \leq a_2 \leq b_2 \leq \ldots \leq a_n \leq b_n$ then $$\bigcup_{i=1}^n \left[a_i,b_i\right]$$ is closed.
Second, $(a,b)$ is open, so the complement $(-\infty,a] \cup [b,\infty)$ is closed. You can combine both examples to come up with a third. The set of integers $\Bbb{Z}$ is also closed. Can you prove it?

Comment: The singleton is of the form $[a,a]$.

Comment: @GitGud: True, but graydad's reason for bringing up singletons specifically appears to be to point out that all finite sets are closed as the first example of a type of answer to this question.

Comment: @GitGud that is certainly true. But I imagine the question was asked assuming that $[a,b]$ is an interval where $a \neq b$

Comment: @graydad I'll be happy to up vote if you add that clarification to the answer.

Comment: @GitGud I tried to generalize in a way that make both our opinions clear. How does it look?

Comment: @graydad I think my comment is still valid, you didn't add the assumption that $a\neq b$.

Comment: @GitGud Fair enough! I have explicitly put it in my answer now.

Answer (score 3):

What about $\{1\} \cup \Big\{\frac{n}{n+1}; n \in \mathbb N \cup\{0\}\Big\}$. There is also the [Cantor Set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set).

Answer (score 1):

Seriously, what about $[0,1] \cup [2,3]$ ?...